# Samba will not accept my password

Tags: 14.04, networking, password, samba, file-sharing

I have recently done a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04lts.

samba is installed and I can see the computers in my workgroup.

I was able to transfer files from a Windows XP computer on my workgroup yesterday.

I can no longer access the files on the Windows XP computer today.

Samba asks for user and password but but it is not accepted. password and user was set using sudo `smbpasswd -a`.

I used the same password as my login. I have changed security settings as recommended in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Here is my `smb.conf`

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[Music]"
Processing section "[Pictures]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
[global]
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
server role = standalone server
map to guest = Bad User
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
unix password sync = Yes
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
name resolve order = bcast, host
dns proxy = No
usershare allow guests = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
idmap config * : backend = tdb
read only = No

[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
create mask = 0700
printable = Yes
print ok = Yes
browseable = No

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[Music]
path = /home/laverne/Music
guest ok = Yes

[Pictures]
path = /home/laverne/Pictures
guest ok = Yes
laverne@laverne-N61PC-M2S:~$ smbclient -L
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Usage: smbclient [-?EgBVNkPeC] [-?|--help] [--usage]

    [-R|--name-resolve=NAME-RESOLVE-ORDER] [-M|--message=HOST]
    [-I|--ip-address=IP] [-E|--stderr] [-L|--list=HOST]
    [-m|--max-protocol=LEVEL] [-T|--tar=<c|x>IXFqgbNan]
    [-D|--directory=DIR] [-c|--command=STRING] [-b|--send-buffer=BYTES]
    [-t|--timeout=SECONDS] [-p|--port=PORT] [-g|--grepable]
    [-B|--browse] [-d|--debuglevel=DEBUGLEVEL]
    [-s|--configfile=CONFIGFILE] [-l|--log-basename=LOGFILEBASE]
    [-V|--version] [--option=name=value]
    [-O|--socket-options=SOCKETOPTIONS] [-n|--netbiosname=NETBIOSNAME]
    [-W|--workgroup=WORKGROUP] [-i|--scope=SCOPE] [-U|--user=USERNAME]
    [-N|--no-pass] [-k|--kerberos] [-A|--authentication-file=FILE]
    [-S|--signing=on|off|required] [-P|--machine-pass] [-e|--encrypt]
    [-C|--use-ccache] [--pw-nt-hash] service <password>
laverne@laverne-N61PC-M2S:~$ smbclient -L laverne-N61PC-M2S
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'
Enter laverne's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
Music           Disk      
Pictures        Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (laverne-N61PC-M2S server (Samba, Ubuntu))
Brother-MFC-885CW Printer   Brother MFC-885CW
Videos          Disk      
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
BRW001E4CC16B21      
                     laverne-N61PC-M2S server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
LIEBROCK_HOME        NETBOOK-01
WORKGROUP            LAVERNE-N61PC-M2S
```

any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding lines bellow to smb.conf solved the problem.

```
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
```

See http://sysadmin.toshiro.biz/services/samba-services/samba-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this worked like a charm,

I have a AIX 7.1 and users on windows 7 and windows 10.

I tried all combinations, windows 10 used to fail on AD.

I am pasting my config, so it will be useful to others.

```
[global]
security = user
netbios name = aix-server-fqdn
password server = AD SERVER
workgroup = WORKGROUP
realm = DOMAIN WITH FQDN
min protocol = SMB2
protocol = SMB2
map to guest = Bad User
```